# Drawing a shape with circles

Tags: flash, animation

The issue I am having is how to tackle forming a logo using circles. I have done one letter manually, however it would take forever to do this with every single letter, and so I am asking here if anyone knew of a faster method.

Requirements:
- Has to fill non-circular letters(i.e. does not have to be precise, but look like it has edges)
- Circles have to animate in, therefore they need to have drop shadow and seem like they are landing in place

This is what I have so far: http://2bitpixel.net/Dots.swf

Answer (score 0):

Particle systems such as the Flint Particle System would automate your task.

http://flintparticles.org/

On their homepage, you see red particles assembling to form words.  This is the logo tween:

http://flintparticles.org/examples/logotween

There is also a similar code tutorial for logo fireworks:

http://flintparticles.org/examples/logo-firework